# Ag-Grid and disabling a button

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to disable a button as long as any row is not selected in my ag-grid. When a row is selected I want to activate a button. Here my code:

app.component.html

```
<button disabled="activeButtons">Disable me</button> <!--option 1-->
<button ng-disabled="activeButtons()">Disable me</button> <!--option 2-->

<ag-grid-angular 
     #agGrid
     style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
     class="ag-theme-balham"
     [enableSorting]="true"
     [enableFilter]="true"
     [rowData]="rowData | async" 
     [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
     rowSelection="multiple">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

app.component.ts

```
getSelectedRows() {
  const selectedNodes = this.agGrid.api.getSelectedNodes();
  return selectedNodes == null;
}
```

How can I notify from the function getSelectedRows to my template button?

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html

```
<button [disabled]="disableButtons">Disable me</button>

<ag-grid-angular 
     #agGrid
     style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
     class="ag-theme-balham"
     [enableSorting]="true"
     [enableFilter]="true"
     [rowData]="rowData | async" 
     [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
     rowSelection="multiple"
     (selectionChanged) = 'onSelectionChanged($event)'>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

app.component.ts

```
onSelectionChanged(event: any){
  var selectedRows =  this.agGrid.api.getSelectedRows();
  this.disableButtons = selectedRows.length === 0;
}
```