# Ag-Grid - Search a row with determined condition

Tags: ag-grid

I want to search in the rows of a ag-grid, if there is any row with a property set an especific value. Should I use the forEachNode of the GridApi function or is there a best way?

app.component.html

```
<button [disabled]="disableButtons">Disable me</button>

<ag-grid-angular 
     #agGrid
     style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" 
     class="ag-theme-balham"
     [enableSorting]="true"
     [enableFilter]="true"
     [rowData]="rowData | async" 
     [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
     rowSelection="multiple"
     (selectionChanged) = 'onSelectionChanged($event)'>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

app.component.ts

```
onSelectionChanged(event: any){
  var rows =  this.agGrid.api. ????? ;
  //any row with property A with value 'XY' ?
  this.disableButtons = ????;
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to disable a button if there is a row has any property with a determinated value

Comment: button inside the row (ag-grid) ?

Comment: no, outside. I am going to edit the question with the layout code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onSelectionChanged(event: any){
  var rows =  this.agGrid.api.getSelectedRows().filter(item=> return item.ExamleFieldName == "exampleValue");
  //any row with property A with value 'XY' ?
  this.disableButtons = rows.length > 0;
}
```

Is that [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655309/4483102) also?

Or you guys working on the same issue?

Comment: It is my post also